# Using Case Statement To Decide Column To Insert Into

Tags: sql, insert, case, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have data that is being inserted from one table to another. During that insert, there are certain transformations happing to some of the data. One example is

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
CASE
    WHEN year(DATE_COLUMN) >= 1000 THEN (Insert into columnA of TARGET_TABLE)
    ELSE (Insert into columnB of TARGET_TABLE)
END
FROM SOURCE_TABLE
```

There are many other columns being inserted into the target table from the source table, but whether the date goes into columnA or columnB depends on the date in the source table's DATE_COLUMN. How would I make sure that the date is being filled in the correct column of the target table following this method?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 2):

You need two `CASE` expressions, one for each column:

```
INSERT INTO target_table (col_name, column_a, column_b)
SELECT 
  column_name,
  CASE WHEN year(date_column) >= 1000 THEN some_column END,
  CASE WHEN year(date_column) < 1000 OR date_column IS NULL THEN some_column END
FROM source_table;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. I'll try this out in my case and let you know if it works. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Btw, to make it simpler and symmetric, your second CASE could be something lke `CASE WHEN year(date_column) >= 1000 THEN null ELSE some_column END`